# .so-type plugin with embedded Python interpreter: How to link/load libpython?

Tags: dynamic-linking, python-c-api, dlopen

I have got the following setup:

```
----------------------------
|     C++ Application      |
----------------------------
              |
          dlopen()s
              |
              v
----------------------------          -------------------
| C++ Plugin with embedded |--links-->| libpython3.8.so |
|    Python interpreter    |          -------------------
----------------------------
              |
            runs
              |
              v
----------------------------
|       Python script      |
----------------------------
              |
           imports
              |
              v
----------------------------
|   Python C extension     |
|   module (e.g., numpy)   |
----------------------------
```

Without any further measures, the import of the Python C extension module from within the Python script fails for the reasons detailed in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8302810), i.e. that the Python extension does not "see" the symbols in libpython.

When calling `dlopen("libpython3.8.so", RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL)` in the C++ plugin as suggested in answers to the aforementioned question, it works. Yet, intermingling build-time dynamic linking (i.e., specifing `-lpython3.8`) and "manual" `dlopen()` calls at run-time somehow does not seem right to me.

Therefore, I am looking for a more stringent solution. My first idea was to skip compile-time linking altogether and fully rely on `dlopen()` to load libpython. As an extra benefit, this would have allowed to make the Python installation user-selectable, by providing an option to specify the path to `libpython` in the config of my plugin. However, the approach does not work as even making use of `RTLD_LAZY`, *variables* in `libpython` have to be resolvable already at the moment when the C++ plugin is loaded by the application.

Vice versa, it could also be desirable to rely on build-time linking only. To my understanding, this would require a link-time option instructing to load `libpython` with the same symbol visibility as achieved by `dlopen()` with `RTLD_GLOBAL`. However, I do not know of any such option and was so far unable to find one.

My questions are:

- Can you think of any better or more stringent solution than both linking `libpython` at build-time and `dlopen()`ing at runtime? It would be an extra bonus if an approach would allow to make `libpython` selectable via plugin config (independent of the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable).
- If you cannot think of any better solution either, what are the risks related to mixing build-time linking and `dlopen()`? In particular,

  - what would happen if - for any reason - another version of libpython was loaded with `dlopen()` than the one that was linked against?
  - are `-lpython3.8` and `dlopen("libpython3.8.so", ...)` equivalent in the sense that they always resolve to the same library file?

Comment: Could you provide compile/link commands that you use? `dlopen`ing libpython prior to loading the plugin should not be needed.

Comment: I'm calling `dlopen()` in the C++ plugin itself, not in host application. That was mistakable due to a now-fixed typo in the question - sorry for that.

I'm compiling with `g++ -std=c++20 -c -g -I/usr/include/python3.8 -fPIC  -MMD -MP -MF FILE.o.d -o FILE.o FILE.cpp` and linking with `g++ -std=c++20 -o plugin.so *.o -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -lpython3.8 -lvamp-sdk -shared -fPIC`.

As mentioned in the question, the extra call to `dlopen()` is only necessary to be able to Python C extension modules. If the Python scripts do not include any of those, everything works just fine.